# std::transform slower than for loops

Tags: c++, matrix, c++17

I thought about implementing a matrix class that used `std::transform` from algorithm for calculation but I came across that in some situations it's faster to write loops.

Having a look add `operator+=` for element wise add. In case the rhs matrix has 1 col while having the same number of rows than the lhs matrix I can do the following:

```
for (auto c = 0; c < cols(); ++c) {
    std::transform(std::execution::par, col_begin(c), col_end(c), rhs.begin(), col_begin(c), std::plus<>());
}
```

or use simple loops:

```
auto lhsval = begin();
auto rhsval= rhs.begin();

for (auto r = 0; r < rows(); ++r) {
   for (auto c = 0; c < cols(); ++c) {
       *lhsval += *rhsval;
       ++lhsval;
   }
   ++rhsval;
}
```

For your information, i wrote an iterator that accepts a step. So the `col_begin()` returns an iterator that will skip other columns in the `operator++`

I timed the difference between both implementations using google benchmark and came to the conclusion that the loop is about 5 times faster than using std::transform. Well maybe there should be a difference, but not a difference that huge.

You can look at the complete code at [my github repo](https://github.com/cemoktra/mlpp/tree/avx-matrix)

[matrix class](https://github.com/cemoktra/mlpp/blob/avx-matrix/src/core/matrix.cpp)
[matrix iterator](https://github.com/cemoktra/mlpp/blob/avx-matrix/src/core/matrix_iterator.h)

Comment: Does the same thing happen without `std::execution::par`? Are you compiling in the release mode?

Comment: Yes the execution policy just changes nothing. Release build yes

Comment: Hint: when asking about performance (not efficiency), the questions is often unanswerable without specifying how do you compile your code. We need - your compiler, your build (debug / release) and your compiler options (mainly optimisations flags).

Comment: @Fureeish gcc 9.2, release build with: set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")

Comment: Please provide a link to the right file in the repo. We also need to see the implementation of the iterators.

Comment: You can try to analyze your code with https://cppinsights.io/ You may find some interesting things.

Comment: IMHO you are running into cache misses here. In first example you iterate multiple times over two not connected memory regions. In second you iterate over only one region with single rhs value which can be easily optimized by the compiler

Comment: @bartop but the difference sounded to big for me for cache misses, but maybe i should go with a specialized version of std::transform for this cases

Comment: @bazz-dee it ain't too big at all. Cache misses (and their subtype, branch misprediction) can cause huge performance issues on low level. Additionally I noticed in your code how is your matrix organized. No wonder iterating over rows and later over columns is faster - cells in rows are close in memory, in one cache line. Try inverting the for loops and check performance then. I am pretty sure that (if compiler does not optimize it out) it will be nearly as slow

Comment: Your code examples do not look equivalent. Make sure they do the same thing. And post a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If I read your code correctly, the elements of the matrices are stored contiguously in a dynamically allocated array. Why can't you just do a `std::transform(m_data, m_data + m_rows*m_cols, rhs.m_data, m_data, std::plus<>());`?

Comment: @Bob__ for internal calculations i could do this. But in this case i cannot skip single columns

Answer (score 1):

Passing `std::execution::par` is asking the library to parallelize this operation. This adds overhead, even if it is just to determine "your problem is too small to parallelize". The number of elements being transformed has to be quite large (sometimes hundreds of thousands or millions) before the parallelization is worthwhile, and requires that you have appropriate hardware (parallelizing on a two-core machine is much less likely to be worth it than on a 64-core machine).

The `for` loop version is much more similar to plain `std::transform` without the `std::execution::par` parameter. If you remove that parameter and the performance difference is still large, please update your question with that information, alongside your compiler version, platform, compiler switches and information about your data set: number of rows/columns, etc.

Comment: Hello. The test data are 1000x1000 matrices. In the comments you see the other information. But i gues sthe comment were right that i just have cache misses. Currently i found a solutin to be fast enough